# Чим префікси "щонай-" і "якнай-" відрізняються від префікса "най-"?

Tags: морфологія, префікс

Словник [CУМ](http://sum.in.ua) надає однакові пояснення для кожного з них:

> **ЩОНАЙ...**, префікс. Уживається для творення форм найвищого ступеня порівняння прикметників і прислівників із значенням найбільшої або найменшої міри якості, напр.: щонайактивніший, щонайвірніший, щонайдовше, щонайдовший, щонайпізніше, щонайпотрібніший, щонайпочесніший, щонайстранніший, щонайтяжчий і т. ін.
>
> **ЯКНАЙ...**, префікс. Уживається для творення форм найвищого ступеня порівняння прикметників і прислівників із значенням найбільшої або найменшої міри якості, напр.: якнайгучніший, якнайгучніше, якнайдокладніший, якнайдокладніше, якнайдужчий, якнайдужче, якнайщиріший, якнайщиріше і т. ін.
>
> **НАЙ...**, префікс. Уживається для творення форм найвищого ступеня порівняння прикметників і прислівників із значенням найбільшої або найменшої міри якості, напр.: найблагородніший, найвідоміший, найзагальніший, найоригінальніший, найсуттєвіший і т. ін.

Чим відрізняються перші два від останнього і одне від одного?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Як на мене, (що/як)най- і просто най- — це кардинально різні речі.

Згідно з моїм інтуїтивним відчуттям:

- «Най…» — це просто [найвищий ступінь](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%8C) порівняння. Швидко — швидший — *найшвидший*, низько — нижче — *найнижчий* і т.д. Показує найвищий рівень *в межах якоїсь групи* (ну, або у всесвіті). Таке є і в російській/англійській мові.
- «Якнай…» я сприймаю як скорочення від «якомога …». *Якнайдокладніший* — *якомога докладніший*, тобто *настільки докладний, наскільки виконавець/виконавці у силах*. Це не про порівняння з іншими, це про *докладання зусиль*. *Біжи найшвидше* — *біжи швидше за всіх*, *біжи якнайшвидше* — *біжи так швидко, як сам зможеш*. Наскільки я можу судити, російською чи англійською це не можна сказати одним словом ("as … as you can").
- «Щонай…» я сприймаю як скорочення від «щосили …». Тобто синонім до «якнай…».

Шкода, не можу зараз це нічим довести. Коли буде час, спробую відредагувати відповідь.

Ще серед «додаткових» ступенів прикметників, що не вписуються в три «класичні» ступені (що є в більшості мов), окрім якнай- і щонай-, я бачу:

- «За…», яке я сприймаю як скорочення від «занадто …». *Занизький* — *занадто низький*. Теж російською чи англійською це не сказати одним словом. Хоч і в українській мові не кожен кількісний прикметник природно поєднується із за-.

Comment: Цікаво, що "щонайбільше" має значення максимуму. Тобто "не більше, ніж". "Якнайбільше" - ні. Можливо це варто якось додати до відповіді, можливо - ні. )

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, так, ця відповідь дуже недосконала. Окрім того, що вона не містить доказів, я ще й невпевнений щодо точного змісту «щонай…». Вже після того, як я написав це — я побачив Вашу цитату: «він — щонайстарший над усіма» — яка мені чомусь особисто сприймається як «він майже найстарший» (хоча я нечасто таке чув у реальному житті, тож можу помилятися). Крім того, мабуть, не вистачає ремарки «„(як/що)най…“ теж *іноді* можуть позначати просто найвищий ступінь». Тобто цю відповідь ще вдосконалювати і вдосконалювати, особливо про «щонай…». Хочете, зроблю її спільноредагованою?

Comment: я у вас вірю ) Приклад з моєї відпові й для мене дуже дивно звучить. Але Квітка-Основ’яненко... У спільноредагованій відповіді наразі не бачу сенсу - гадаю, або хтось відповість ліпше за нас обох, або вам варто ще подумати й оновити відповідь. Принаймні я не готовий її редагувати - я не знаю, як ув'язати цей факт з рештою відповіді.

Answer (score 5):

Згідно з ["Як ми говоримо"](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/stupenyuvannya-yakisnyh-prykmetnykiv), *що-* і *як-* додаються для підсилення на кшталт *найнай-*

Утім, зазвичай (суб'єктивно) вони вживаються, коли треба зробити все можливе, як можна бачити в одному з наведених там прикладів:

> Данилові довелося лише думати про якнайскорішу реалізацію свого плану

Рідше (суб'єктивно) для підсилення, як в іншому наведеному там прикладі:

> Він — щонайстарший над усіма.

Різниця між *як-* і *що-* мені наразі невідома.